# PHP comparing 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I've stuck in some certain problem, I've got two arrays which are the output of some other methods:

```
$firstArray = ['Johny Mao'=>'A', 'Kate Young'=>'B', 'Adam Mink'=>'C'];
$secondArray = [
    ['Johny Mao','A'],
    ['Kate Young', 'B'],
    ['Adam Mink', 'C']    
];
```

How should I change these two arrays in order two compare them?
I need to know wheter they consist the same information.
Probably I should use array_diff methods but first I need to change arrays structure to be able to compar them.
Hope expressed clearly :)

Comment: How? That's up to you. There's no one single answer for this. You're basically fishing for oppinions.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new array (or modify the second array) to key/value pairs matching the first array

```
$newArray = array_combine(
    array_column($secondArray, 0),
    array_column($secondArray, 1)
);
```

and then do your comparison

Comment: wouldn't really work. first one is a flat array name -> value. second one is an array of arrays of values. no keys.

Comment: @MarcB -why wouldn't it work? This maps the second array so a simple array with names -> values, matching the first array; and it should then be possible to compare using something like [array_diff_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)

Comment: ewps. right. sorry. mondays... didn't even see _column in there.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, assuming you don't need to check if elements in first array aren't in second array.

```
function areArraysEqual($firstArray, $secondArray)
{
    if(count($firstArray) != count($secondArray))
    {
        return false;
    }
    foreach($secondArray as $key => $value)
    {
        if(!isset($firstArray[$value[0]]) || $firstArray[$value[0]] != $value[1])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

$firstArray = ['Johny Mao'=>'A', 'Kate Young'=>'B', 'Adam Mink'=>'C'];
$secondArray = [
    ['Johny Mao','A'],
    ['Kate Young', 'B'],
    ['Adam Mink', 'C']    
];
$result = areArraysEqual($firstArray, $secondArray);
var_dump($result);
```

Edit:

This code below should now take into account if elements in the first array aren't in the second array.

```
<?php
function isValueIn2dArray(&$array, $secondDimensionKey, $value)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $array2)
    {
        if($array2[$secondDimensionKey] == $value)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function areArraysEqual($firstArray, $secondArray)
{
    if(count($firstArray) != count($secondArray))
    {
        return false;
    }
    foreach($secondArray as $key => $value)
    {
        if(!isset($firstArray[$value[0]]) || $firstArray[$value[0]] != $value[1])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    foreach($firstArray as $key => $value)
    {
        if(!isValueIn2dArray($secondArray, 0, $key))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

$firstArray = ['Johny Mao'=>'A', 'Kate Young'=>'B', 'Adam Mink'=>'C'];
$secondArray = [
    ['Johny Mao','A'],
    ['Kate Young', 'B'],
    ['Adam Mink', 'C']    
];
$result = areArraysEqual($firstArray, $secondArray);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I need to be sure that both arrays are the same. In both arrays always should be the same amount of items and key with corresponding value (first array) or two values (in second array). At firts glance it seems to me that your solution works fine.

Comment: I've updated my post to now take into account what was missing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I 'll check it tommorow at work. It's satisfactorily to know that amount of items in arrays are different I don't need to know in which are less items, so throwing an exception will be fine.

Comment: One question here $firstArray[$value[0]] != $value[1] you compare value from firstArray which is "A" with value from second one which is also "A"?

Comment: Np. And yes that is correct, it ensures the values are the same in both arrays for the matching key.

Comment: There is still sth. wrong. The output of these 2 arrays is:  Array
 (
    [1] => Array
      (
             [0] => Johny Mao
           [1] => A
         )
 
   [2] => Array
         (
          [1] => B
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
             [0] => Kate Young
           [1] => C
       )
 )
 Array
 (
    [Johny Mao] => A
     [Adam Mink] => B
     [Kate Young] => C
)
So the problem is in $firstArray[$value[0]] != $value[1] condition.

Comment: I'm not sure which arrays you are outputting? The arrays shouldn't be getting modified. That condition looks fine to me.

Comment: The output of both arrays is:                                                                                         First Array:
Array
 (
  [1] => Array
   (
    [0] => Johny Mao
    [1] => A
   )

   [2] => Array
   (
     [0] => Adam Mink
    [1] => B
    )

 [3] => Array
   (
    [0] => Kate Young
    [1] => C
 )

Second Array:

       Array
       (
         [Johny Mao] => A
         [Adam Mink] => B
         [Kate Young] => C
      )

Answer (score 0):

The comments are spot on. This is the developers idea.

Without using array_diff or something:

```
    function array_are_same($firstarray,$secondarray){
        foreach ($firstarray as $key => $value) {
            if (!array_key_exists($key, $secondarray)
                || $secondarray[$key] !== $value){
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```